# Is this a good way to create a CORS filter in Java that allow any origin?

Tags: java, spring, servlet-filters

I need to do a cors filter in java and I'd like to allow any origin, headers and methods, I create the following filter:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest req  = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.getHeader("Origin"));
    resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

    if("OPTIONS".equals(req.getMethod())) {
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", req.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method"));
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", req.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");

        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}
}
```

I was using `*` to allow any origin, header and method, but I need to send Cookie from browser, and when the origin header is `*`, the browser is showing the following message in the console

> The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

So I'm using the `"Origin"` header from request as the value to `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin";`

this approach will work if I receive request from multiples origins at same time or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this will work assuming there's `Origin` header in the request. For a more comprehensive way of handling it, I'd suggest you to take a look in Spring's [CorsConfiguration.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/cors/CorsConfiguration.java#L438-L461):

```
    @Nullable
    public String checkOrigin(@Nullable String requestOrigin) {
        if (!StringUtils.hasText(requestOrigin)) {
            return null;
        }
        if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(this.allowedOrigins)) {
            return null;
        }

        if (this.allowedOrigins.contains(ALL)) {
            if (this.allowCredentials != Boolean.TRUE) {
                return ALL;
            }
            else {
                return requestOrigin;
            }
        }
        for (String allowedOrigin : this.allowedOrigins) {
            if (requestOrigin.equalsIgnoreCase(allowedOrigin)) {
                return requestOrigin;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

by accepting any origin you are basically breaking the idea of CORS and you let everybody to use your services (ok, you have auth but a DOS attack is also possible).

The idea of CORS is to let your frontend to talk only some specific (yours) backend.

The vulnerability is for the situation when somebody will inject some malicious javascript that want to use some ugly backends, or some foreign javascript want to use your backend services.

I hope this will help you,
cheers